# How to include data to object if element is not falsy?

Tags: javascript

I have the map:

```
map(([reportProperties, reportObjectsProperties, textProperties, visibleText]) => {
                return { reportObjectsProperties, reportProperties, textProperties, visibleText };
            }),
```

I try to check if all parameters are not falsy include them to result object like this:

```
map(([reportProperties, reportObjectsProperties, textProperties, visibleText]) => {
                if(visibleText)
                   return { reportObjectsProperties, reportProperties, textProperties, visibleText };
                if(reportObjectsProperties && reportObjectsProperties.length)
                   return { reportObjectsProperties, reportProperties, textProperties, visibleText };
```

....

```
            }),
```

How to make this more elegant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to look into [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method paired with
[Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to filter out the falsy values. And pair it with a reduce function to reconstruct the new object

I would take this into the following direction:

```js
const arr = [{a: true, b: true, c: false}, {a: false, b: true}]

const excludeKeys = ["c"]


let result = arr.map(obj => {
  return Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, value]) => !excludeKeys.includes(key) && value)
    .reduce((prev, [key, value]) => ({...prev, [key]: value}), {})
})
```

This provides a functional and pretty generic interface for filtering out the falsy / excluded object key / values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your object is an array, you can check if all values exists using `every` method. And you don't need `map` there because you don't do a transformation on your object.

instead of

```
.map(arr => {
 ... return arr;
});
```

do

```
.filter(row => row.every(cell => typeof cell !== undefined && cell !== null));
```

Comment: Some parameters are array some not (object, boolean)

Comment: In your example `map(([reportProperties, reportObjectsProperties, textProperties, visibleText])' using `[` and `]` map will receive everytime an array (as an object). So, your entire object (before  applying`map`) is a matrix